# How to pass addition attributes or arguments to a Object.new in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have a simple

```
@redemption = Redemption.new(params[:redemption])
```

I need to pass :user_id => current_user.id into this new Redem

I have tried:

```
 @redemption = Redemption.new(params[:redemption], :user_id => current_user.id)
```

this doesn't build the Redemption with a user_id...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params` is a Hash, so if you want additional attributes in `create`, just add them to `params`, e.g.:

```
params[:redemption][:user_id] = current_user.id

@redemption = Redemption.new params[:redemption]
```

Or, if you want to add multiple attributes at once, use [`Hash#merge`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge), e.g.:

```
redemption_params = params[:redemption].merge :user_id   => current_user.id,
                                              :some_attr => :foo

@redemption = Redemption.new redemption_params
```

In this particular case, though, you could probably use a shorter syntax, e.g.:

```
current_user.redemptions.create params[:redemption]
```